# How i can send message to individual Line User?

Tags: line, messaging

I want to send message to private user not in any bot or group. How i can send ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please give me more details, what you are expecting

Comment: you can create bot  and send messages , i don't find any API to send one to one message   https://developers.line.biz/en/docs/messaging-api/overview/

Comment: At bot i am already sending message properly, but i want to send on specific user, just like notification.

Comment: @MujtabaAhmad, Did you solved this?

Answer (score -1):

Line have API to send to one private user.

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/push \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {channel access token}' \
-d '{
    "to": "U4af4980629...",
    "messages":[
        {
            "type":"text",
            "text":"Hello, world1"
        },
        {
            "type":"text",
            "text":"Hello, world2"
        }
    ]
}'
```

See the documentation: https://developers.line.biz/en/reference/messaging-api/#send-push-message